# Error propagation for exponents

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis

I was told that since $x^n = x\cdot x\cdot x \cdot \ldots \cdot x$ that the error is $$\delta f = f_{\text{best}} |n|\lbrace \frac {\delta_x}{f_{\text{best}}} \rbrace$$ where $f$ is a function of $(x)$. What about $n\notin \mathbb Z, n \in \mathbb Q$? This type of proof will not work. What's the proof for that special case?

Comment: What is $f_{\textrm{best}}$? When you say "error propagation of exponents", do you mean that the exponent is the independent variable here, or do you really mean "error propagation with power functions"?

Comment: @march the x is the independent variable and $n$ is some constant. $f_{\text{best}}$ is the best estimate.

Comment: Okay. Your title is a little misleading (hence my question). In addition, don't the $f_{\textrm{best}}$'s cancel out in your case? Is the $\{ \}$ some special notation?

Comment: @march no, I just put them there for clarity.

Comment: Which means that the $f_{\textrm{best}}$'s cancel out, leading to an expression that I think is incorrect for $\delta f$. In fact, your expression is then not dimensionally correct. If the $f_{\textrm{best}}$ in the denominator is actually $x_{\textrm{best}}$, then your expression matches the expression in the answer below.

Comment: @march It is dimensionally correct, since $\delta_x$ has units.

Comment: Well then I'm not understanding what $\delta_x$ is. I was interpreting it as $\delta x$, in which case it has the same units as $x$, which clearly doesn't have the same units as $\delta f$ (because it has the same units as $f(x) = x^n$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For error propagation for one variable, it is best to use

$$\delta f(x) = \left|\frac{d f(x)}{d x}\right| \delta x$$

which is to say that the uncertainty in the function should be weighted with the derivative(or how sensitive the function is to changing the variable)

Now for your example,

$$f(x) = x^n \Rightarrow \delta f(x) = \left|n x^{n-1} \right| \delta x$$

regardless of $n$ integer or not. EDIT: This is assuming the errors $\delta x$ follow Gaussian statistics as in the below comment.

Comment: Any explanation of this ratios rule?

Comment: That is a good question. I suppose I've always used this without any explanation of why. I'm looking at that now...

This seems to only come up if $f(x) = A x$, with $A$ constant, but certainly should make sense for any $f(x)$.

Comment: I'm just going to change this answer. $\delta f/f = \delta x/x$ is a good approximation, but perhaps there is a case where it isn't good. Most sources point to using the above formula.

Comment: Can you explain how this matches the form given by the OP?

Comment: The way to do full blown error propagation is to compute the transformations of the statistical distributions involved. These simple transformations of "uncertainty" are usually derived by assuming the errors are Gaussian and tracking how the standard deviation transforms during data analysis.

Comment: This formula just assumes the errors are small, not that they're Gaussian.

Comment: I'd certainly be open to upvoting a more rigorous answer. I'm not sure that my answer tells you why we use that formula for $\delta f$...